# Why is this form validation with dynamic input values not working?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components, angular-validation

*Just started practicing angular...*
I have made a reactive form (in parent component) in angular whose values are dynamically filled by child component.
On submitting this form null values are saved since form is not detecting the values although values are visible in input fields.

Note: input values are showing in parent component (child to parent communication is successful)

Here is the necessary code:

**Child component- ts file**

```
@Output() messageToEmit = new EventEmitter<string>();
@Output() messageToEmit1 = new EventEmitter<string>();
@Output() messageToEmit2 = new EventEmitter<string>();
@Output() messageToEmit3 = new EventEmitter<string>();

save(selectedItem: any, index: number)
{
var num1 = selectedItem.f;
var num2 = selectedItem.l;
var num3 = selectedItem.e;
var num4 = selectedItem.p;

this.messageToEmit.emit(num1);
this.messageToEmit1.emit(num2);
this.messageToEmit2.emit(num3);
this.messageToEmit3.emit(num4);
 }
```

**Child component- html file**

```
  <table class="w3-table-all">
<thead>
  <tr class="w3-red">
    <th>First Name</th>
    <th>Last Name</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Password</th>
     <th>Edit / Update</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<tr *ngFor="let thing of things; let i = index;">   
  <td><input type="text" value="{{thing.f}}" id="{{ 'f' + i }}"> </td>
  <td><input type="text" value="{{thing.l}}"  id="{{ 'l' + i }}"> </td>
  <td><input type="text" value="{{thing.e}}"  id="{{ 'u' + i }}"> </td>
  <td><input type="text" value="{{thing.p}}"  id="{{ 'p' + i }}"> </td>
  <td >
    <button (click) = "save(thing,i)">Edit</button>
    </td>
  </tr> 
  </table>
```

**Parent component - ts file**

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
edited_values: string;
edited_values1: string;
edited_values2: string;
edited_values3: string;
edited_values4:  number;

name = 'Registration';
signupForm:FormGroup;
FirstName:string = "";
LastName:string = "";
Email:string = "";
Password:string = "";

constructor(
private frmbuilder: FormBuilder,
)
{
this.signupForm= frmbuilder.group({
fname:new FormControl('', [
Validators.required,
Validators.maxLength(50),
Validators.minLength(3),
Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ]*$')
]),
lname:new FormControl('', [
Validators.required,
Validators.maxLength(50),
Validators.minLength(3),
Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ]*$')
]),
 email:['',[Validators.required,Validators.email]],
userpassword:new FormControl('', [
Validators.required,
Validators.maxLength(50)
])
});
} 
ngOnInit(){
}

postdata(signupForm:any)
{
this.FirstName=signupForm.controls.fname.value;
this.LastName=signupForm.controls.lname.value;
this.Email=signupForm.controls.email.value;
this.Password=signupForm.controls.userpassword.value;

this.signupForm.reset();
}

getMessage(message: string) {
this.edited_values = message;
}
getMessage1(message1: string) {
this.edited_values1 = message1;
}
getMessage2(message2: string) {
this.edited_values2 = message2;
}
getMessage3(message3: string) {
this.edited_values3 = message3;
 }
reset(){
this.signupForm.reset();
}
}
```

**Parent component- html file**

```
<form id="contact" [formGroup]='signupForm' (ngSubmit)="postdata(signupForm)">
<h3> Register Now! </h3>  
<div class = "form-group">
  <input type="text" formControlName='fname' placeholder="your First name" value={{edited_values}}>
</div>
<div *ngIf="signupForm.controls.fname.invalid && signupForm.controls.fname.touched">
<small> Enter name please (only letters)!  </small>
</div>
<br>
<div class = "form-group"> 
<input type="text" formControlName='lname' placeholder="your Last name"
value={{edited_values1}}>
</div>
<div *ngIf="signupForm.controls.lname.invalid && signupForm.controls.lname.touched">
<small> Enter name please (only letters)!  </small>
</div>
<br>
<div class = "form-group">
<input type="text" formControlName='email' placeholder="your Email id"
value={{edited_values2}}>
</div>
<div *ngIf="signupForm.controls.email.invalid && signupForm.controls.email.touched">
<small>  Email is invalid  </small>
</div>
<br>
<div class = "form-group">
<input type="Password" formControlName='userpassword' placeholder="your password"
value={{edited_values3}}>
</div>
<div *ngIf="signupForm.controls.userpassword.invalid && signupForm.controls.userpassword.touched">
<small> Must enter password in correct format: min 8 characters, at least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 
1 number, 1 special:  </small>
</div>
  <br>
    <div>      
   <button type="submit" > Submit </button>
   <button type="reset" (click) = "reset()"> Reset </button>
 </div>
 </form>
 </div>
 <app-edit 
 (messageToEmit)="getMessage($event)"
 (messageToEmit1)="getMessage1($event)"
 (messageToEmit2)="getMessage2($event)"
 (messageToEmit3)="getMessage3($event)"
 (messageToEmit4)="getMessage4($event)" 
 ></app-edit>
```

Comment: You’re not doing anything in your parent to set any form values?

Comment: @MikeOne I am using child component to parent comp. communication.In the parent component html- inside input tags, values are set by data-binding inside {{}}. Also last few lines in this html file receive values from child component

Comment: Value is only for an initial setting. I think you might have to rethink this a bit.

Comment: What you want is actually pretty simple and can also be done without all the different event handlers..

Comment: @MikeOne actually what i have put here is only necessary code which might seem as initial setting. Actually the values are coming from child component on every click of button. My problem is, this form is not detecting the values which are dynamically binded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@ASHISH, when you use ReactiveForms  NOT use [value], in the inputs, it's only formControlName

```
<!---WRONG--->
<input type="text" formControlName='fname' placeholder="your First name" value={{edited_values}}>

<!--OK-->
<input type="text" formControlName='fname' placeholder="your First name" >
```

And you need change the value using the "method" [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue), so yours functions getMessage must be like

```
getMessage(message: string) {
   this.signupForm.get('fname').setValue(message)
}
```